# jQuery addClass() only semi-adding class

Tags: jquery

I need to add a class using jQuerys addClass-method. It works fine in all of my other code but on this particular one, it adds the word "class" to the element but doesn't add the actual class.

So - before I click the hamburgermenu-button it looks like this: `<body>`, when I click the hamburgermenu-button, my html looks like this: `<body class>` but I want it to look like `<body class="no-scroll">`. I can also see it blinking in developer tools in my browser every time I click the button so SOMETHING is happening but not what I want it to.

I'm using this exact line of code in another function (see the last one provided) and it works fine.

Earlier I had a removeClass on the body-element, but I've removed all of that and it still doesn't work.

The function where it doesn't work:

```
    $('.hamburgermenu-button').click(function() {
        $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('d-xs-none');    
        $('.hamburgermenu-button').toggleClass('collapsed'); 
        $('.main-menu-container').addClass('sticky nav-show');
        $('#search-extended').slideUp(200);
        $("#search-icon").removeClass("show");   
        $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
    });
```

The function where it works:

```
headerSearchVisibility: function(visible) {
    'use strict';

    if(visible) {
        $('#headerSearch').css('z-index',2);
        $('#headerSearchResults').slideDown(200);
        $('#overlay').show();
        if((window).matchMedia("(max-width: 767.98px)").matches) {
            $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
        }
    } else {
        $('#headerSearchResults').slideUp(200);
        $('#overlay').fadeOut(200);
    }
},
```

I've updated my code in this question since people seemed to focus on the wrong thing.

Comment: `$('body').not('header')` doesn't make sense, since a `<body>` element cannot be a `<header>` element. Do you mean `.not('.header')` (aka body without the `.header` class)?

Comment: No, in this code the header element lies inside body, and I want it to apply to everything except that. But I've tried removing ```.not('header')``` and it doesn't work either

Comment: you can try "body:not(header)" this is a css selector

Comment: `$('body *:not(.header)').addClass('no-scroll');`, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have stuff in the header that folds out that I need to scroll. But I don't want the rest of the site (the background) to scroll when they are folded out, which is why I want to apply the class to everything (body) except the header.

Comment: The "not header"-part however is not relevant to my problem. Since even if I remove it I have the same problem - that the class is not applied to my body-element

Comment: Probably the button is running the JS and then loading a new page which (effectively) resets everything, but you haven't provided a [mcve] so it is hard to tell for sure.

Comment: I've tried adding preventDefault and stopPropagation - same problem still

Comment: The code looks fine, maybe you have another click event bound to `.hamburgermenu-button` somewhere in the code?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it either, I only use it in some other places to add a class to .hamburgermenu-button (such as ```$(".hamburgermenu-button").addClass("collapsed");```) Which shouldn't affect this.

Comment: It seems to be the class in some way. If i try adding another class, it works fine. It's just the "no-scroll"-class it has problems with... I cannot figure out why, since it works fine in the other function.

Answer (score -1):

From what i can understand with you example, you are looking for a body element who is not a header element.

But not doesn't work like that : http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>

$( "li" ).not( ":even" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

In this example it will search for every odd li elements.

I suggest you to use children() or find() element and exclude the header element.

Comment: No. You've latched on to a weird bit of the code instead of reading the actual question. The OP explicitly said the problem had nothing to do with the header element in the comments.

Comment: Yes, it was very clear. Thank you for your patience and tolerance quentin.